# Initialize comparison datatable

Tags: java

This code doesn't look too good.  Could anyone help me format it?

```
private void initComparisonDatatable() {
    List<BrandProfitAndLoss> brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable = new ArrayList<BrandProfitAndLoss>();
    BrandProfitAndLoss brandProfitAndLossCurrentYear = new BrandProfitAndLoss();
    BrandProfitAndLoss brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear = new BrandProfitAndLoss();
    // if the selected year is null and the previous year is not null
    if(brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossList().size() <= 0 && brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossComparisonList().size() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossComparisonList().size(); i++){
            brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear = brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossComparisonList().get(i);
            brandProfitAndLossCurrentYear = new BrandProfitAndLoss(brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossComparisonList().get(i).getDate(), brandActionForm.getDateMode(), Consts.CURRENT_YEAR);
            brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable.add(brandProfitAndLossCurrentYear);
            brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable.add(brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear);
            brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable.add(new BrandProfitAndLoss().getAllRateComparisonRecords(brandProfitAndLossCurrentYear
                                                     , brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear));
        }
    }
    // the selected year is not null
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossList().size(); i++){
            brandProfitAndLossCurrentYear = brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossList().get(i);
            brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable.add(brandProfitAndLossCurrentYear);
            if(brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossComparisonList().size() > 0){
                brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear = brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossComparisonList().get(i);
                brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable.add(brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear);
                brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable.add(new BrandProfitAndLoss().getAllRateComparisonRecords(brandProfitAndLossCurrentYear
                                                    , brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear));
            }
            else {
                brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear = new BrandProfitAndLoss(brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossList().get(i).getDate(), brandActionForm.getDateMode(), Consts.CURRENT_YEAR);
                brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable.add(brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear);
                brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable.add(new BrandProfitAndLoss().getAllRateComparisonRecords(brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossList().get(i)
                                                    , brandProfitAndLossPreviousYear));
            }
        }
    }
    brandActionForm.setBrandProfitLossComparisonListForDatatable(brandProfitAndLossComparisonDatatable);
}
```

Comment: What is this method supposed to do in plain English? Method name doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some problems that could be seen without actually understanding code:

- Unhelpful and possibly misleading comments: `// the selected year is not null`
- Repeating type in variable name : `brandProfitAndLossCurrentYear`
- Using ad hoc code instead of using appropriate library methods: `list.size() <= 0` instead of `list.isEmpty()` and `list.size() > 0` instead of `!list.isEmpty()`
- Long method doing more than one thing: `initComparisonDatatable` retrieve data from form, calculate something based using said data, modify form using calculated data
- Feature Envy: Since `initComparisonDatatable` acts on `brandActionForm` and uses only data from `brandActionForm` it belongs to `brandActionForm`.
- Repetitive code: body of the three loops are repeated with minor variations.

There are probable design issues, but those cannot be addressed properly without further clarification. For example `new BrandProfitAndLoss().getAllRateComparisonRecords` suggests `BrandProfitAndLoss` has some data access code in it, therefore should be moved elsewhere; it probably is a class method instead of an instance method; and since it is a class method it probably has dependency issues, I can smell an evil singleton from here.

How refactored code could look like, (since loops and conditional statements have been changed these will definitely break something, so ***do not try to use it in production*** without proper unit testing):

```
    private void initComparisonDatatable() {
        List<BrandProfitAndLoss> comparisonDatatable = listForDatatable(
                brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossComparisonList(), 
                brandActionForm.getBrandProfitLossList(), 
                brandActionForm.getDateMode());

        brandActionForm.setBrandProfitLossComparisonListForDatatable(comparisonDatatable);
    }

    private static List<BrandProfitAndLoss> listForDatatable(
            List<BrandProfitAndLoss> brandProfitLossComparisonList,
            List<BrandProfitAndLoss> brandProfitLossList, Object dateMode) {
        List<BrandProfitAndLoss> comparisonDatatable = new ArrayList<BrandProfitAndLoss>();

        int prevYearSize = brandProfitLossComparisonList.size();
        int currentYearSize = brandProfitLossList.size();
        int size = Math.max(prevYearSize, currentYearSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            BrandProfitAndLoss ofPreviousYear = (i < prevYearSize) 
                    ? brandProfitLossComparisonList.get(i) 
                    : null;

            BrandProfitAndLoss ofCurrentYear = (i < currentYearSize) 
                    ? brandProfitLossList.get(i) 
                    : null;

            if (ofPreviousYear == null) {
                ofPreviousYear = new BrandProfitAndLoss(
                        ofCurrentYear.getDate(), dateMode, Consts.CURRENT_YEAR);
            }

            if (ofCurrentYear == null) {
                ofCurrentYear = new BrandProfitAndLoss(
                        ofPreviousYear.getDate(), dateMode, Consts.CURRENT_YEAR);
            }

            comparisonDatatable.add(ofCurrentYear);
            comparisonDatatable.add(ofPreviousYear);
            comparisonDatatable
                    .add(new BrandProfitAndLoss().getAllRateComparisonRecords(
                            ofCurrentYear, ofPreviousYear));
        }

        return comparisonDatatable;
    }
```